# How should you serve front end code if I want it decoupled entirely from backend?

Tags: frontend, backend, web-deployment

We want the front end to be completely decoupled from the backend with REST API connecting them. In that case, the front end is just html/js/css. In that case, how do you deploy the front end?

Most CI tools assume that we want to deploy a node.js application or something similar, which is not really what we are looking for? I guess in theory we can setup something like apache and deploy there?

Comment: If it's just static files, you can deploy it most anywhere. To github pages, for example. Or an S3 bucket even.

Comment: But it's not so easy to make s3 a web server with a CI/CD is it?

Comment: Depends. Can you make your CI tool upload to s3? That's all you need. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html